# Структура системных DLL библиотек

Tags: c++, windows, dll, взлом

Пускай в процессе A.exe есть функция

```
int _stdcall func(int a);
```

по адресу `0x1234`. Нам надо вызвать её из другого процесса. Делается это так

```
CreateRemoteThread(hProcess, 0, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)0x1234, (void*)100, 0, 0);
```

В адресном пространстве A.exe начинает выполняться функция `func(100)` в отдельном потоке.
Теперь я хочу вызвать системную функцию. Например, узнать виртуальный адрес программы, вызвав `GetModuleHandleA(NULL)`:

```
HMODULE hModule = GetModuleHandleA("kernel32.dll");
void *func = GetProcAddress(hModule, "GetModuleHandleA");
HANDLE ThreadID = CreateRemoteThread(hProcess, 0, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)func, 0, 0, 0);
WaitForSingleObject(ThreadID, INFINITE);
void *baseAddr;
GetExitCodeThread(ThreadID, (LPDWORD)&baseAddr);
```

Как получается, что функция `GetModuleHandleA` имеет одинаковый адрес в разных процессах? Всегда ли такой код будет работать корректно?
Проверил, что во всех процессах адрес библиотеки kernel32 имеет одинаковый адрес. Скомпилировал программу, у которой базовый адрес совпадает с адресом библиотеки. Приложение не запускалось с кодом 0xc0000018 - конфликт указанного диапазона адресов и адресного пространства.

Answer (score 1):

Если программа 32-битная, а адрес отрицательный и система не запущена в режиме `/3GB` или программа, в которой определялся адрес не поддерживает работу в этом режиме, то он будет одинаков во всех процессах. Здесь имеется в виду именно одинаковость для разных процессов, но не константность адреса.

По крайней мере, я так думаю.

[Подробнее о памяти в Windows.](http://bbs.vbstreets.ru/viewtopic.php?p=6784461#p6784461)

Comment: Вроде бы Microsoft добавила ASLR даже для адресов в области ядра: https://habrahabr.ru/company/eset/blog/282744/.

Comment: Отрицательный адрес? Это который выше 0x7FFFFFFF?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, да.

Comment: Адреса библиотек и доступные функции из них близки к границе 0x7FFFFFFF, но не заходят за неё

Answer (score 0):

Библиотека kernel32.dll действительно имеет одинаковый базовый адрес во всех процессах, так сделано специально. Это поведение не документировано, но хорошо известно, и многие программы полагаются на это. Это нужно как раз для того, чтобы отладчики и профилировщики могли загрузить свою DLL в адресное пространство исследуемого процесса, передав адрес LoadLibrary в CreateRemoteThread.

Начиная с Windows Vista, для системных библиотек действует ASLR, но случайный базовый адрес все равно одинаков для всех процессов и определяется в момент загрузки системы.

Источник: [Why are certain DLLs required to be at the same base address system-wide?](http://www.nynaeve.net/?p=198)